# Time series database design - merging historical and forecast data

Tags: database, excel, database-design, pivot-table

I'm relatively new to database design. I would like to build a database based on some data which is already stored in a server. Below is the details of the tables in the server:
Table 1: Historical data table:
ProductName
Date
AmountSold

Table 2: Static product table:
ProductID
ProductName
Category
Factory

These data are located in the server. The historical data exists from 2000 up to present. I already loaded these data into access and there is a link between the server and access.

Every year we make a forecast on how much products are going to be sold. My idea was to combine historical data with the forecast data, import data into excel and use pivot charts to display the results. So I could see date in x axis and historical sale and forecast sale in y access. Initially I was thinking to make a forecast table as below:
Forecast table:
ProductName
ForecastDate
ForecastSale

The problem is since the two tables (forecast and historical) have two different time ranges (one from 2000 to 2015 and forecast table from 2016-2026), I cannot merge them using queries. This means that I can not use pivottable features such as slicer, etc and make a dashboard.

I appreciate if someone can help me out here.

Comment: Please explain what "cannot merge them using queries" means and why "the two tables have two different time ranges" means that you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Forcast table with the same columns as the Historical table. You can UNION them into a Combined table that represents a timeline of past dates with actual data and future dates with predicted data. You could then:

> So I could see date in x axis and historical sale and forecast sale in y access.

If instead of date you wanted "month" or "season" in the x axis, so that other columns' data is not distinguishable by x value (ie before & after the present) then you can plot y values labeled by date (or a function of it like 'historical' vs 'forecast').

Comment: Thx for the answer. But this doesn't solve my problem as I get all "before and after present" sale data in one column after running the UNION. I would like to have a final table like following: ProductName, Date (both before and after present), AmountSold, ForecastSale. I don't know it is possible to get a such a query. Any other approach would be appreciated (such as better design of tables and make a query using relationships, etc).

Comment: Please address my comment to your question. Also you are not explaining something, because since the actual and forecast dates don't overlap a date can only have *one* of AmountSold or ForecastSale.

Comment: What I meant by "cannot merge them using queries" is to have a combined table in which I can have both historical and forecast data. I mentioned the design for such table in my previous comments. The reason I want to a separate field for Amountsold and ForecastSale is two folds; 1. I do forecast every year. Lets say for 2014 historical data, I already have forecast data which I did on previous year. So I have values both for amountsold and forecastsale. 2. historical data are coming from a server-based database and eventually I'll get historical data for the forecast dates. I hope I am clear.